Custom predefined date range Google Looker studio
At the moment I'm building a dashboard in Looker studio to analyse the efficiency of a process which mainly involves website interactions. This process happens 6 times a year in date ranges of two weeks. Two examples are:

28 Augustus / 11 September -> Period 1
18 September / 2 October -> Period 2

I would like to have a control element so that users of the dashboard can select these predefined date ranges. The dashboard should be showing the data of the selected date range. I've tried to create a calculated field that when Period_1 is selected the date range is 28 augustus / 11 september is shown.
Example of preferred solution
Calculated field for control
Does someone have a solution for the issue above?
I've tried to create a control field which works with a calculated field selecting the chosen date range.

Why don't you build simply build a calculated field based on Date? Either in the data source or directly in the
CASE
WHEN Date >= "2023-08-28" AND Date <= "2023-09-11" THEN "Period 01"
WHEN Date >= "2023-09-18" AND Date <= "2023-10-02" THEN "Period 02"
ELSE "(Other)"
END

Mind you will have to make sure the dates are also properly selected either through the data selector or the graph date settings for this to work.

Unfortunately, the suggested solution does not work because the operator does not work for the Date field. Therefore, I am not able to make this calculated field. Furthermore, the idea is that users will use the filter to get the data of the selected period, by selecting the dates in the graph date settings this will not work.
